# Make button Invisible after 3 seconds, but do not make it invisible if a user scrolled up

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling, android-button, invisible

In android, I have a button that appears when a user scrolls up, and disappears otherwise. However, also, when it appears, I am trying to make it disappear again after 3 seconds, if the user stopped scrolling (after 3 seconds of being idle). I tried the following code,

```
   //detecting whether the user is scrolling up or down, to make the refresh button visible/invisible
        listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            int scrollEventListSize = 5;
            float lastY;
            // Used to correct for occasions when user scrolls down(/up) but the onTouchListener detects it incorrectly. We will store detected up-/down-scrolls with -1/1 in this list and evaluate later which occured more often
            List<Integer> downScrolledEventsHappened;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                float diff = 0;
                if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
                    lastY = event.getY();
                    downScrolledEventsHappened = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_MOVE){
                    diff = event.getY() - lastY;
                    lastY = event.getY();

                    if(diff>0)
                        downScrolledEventsHappened.add(1);
                    else
                        downScrolledEventsHappened.add(-1);

                    //List needs to be filled with some events, will happen very quickly
                    if(downScrolledEventsHappened.size() == scrollEventListSize+1){
                        downScrolledEventsHappened.remove(0);
                        int res=0;
                        for(int i=0; i<downScrolledEventsHappened.size(); i++){
                            res+=downScrolledEventsHappened.get(i);
                        }

                        if (res > 0) {
                            Log.i("INFO", "Scrolled up");
                            refreshButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.i("INFO", "Scrolled down");
                            refreshButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false; // don't interrupt the event-chain
            }
        });





//Removing refresh button when user stops scrolling up or already at the top of the list.
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

     refreshButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}, 3000);



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(firstVisibleItem == 0 && listIsAtTop()){
            System.out.println("List at Top....Refresh Button is disappearing...");
            refreshButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

This code however, is not exactly giving me what I want. It is true that the button disappears after 3 seconds of the user being idle, but it also does so, while the user is scrolling up again! I mean, I need a mechanism in which the after-3-seconds disappearing idea to be canceled when the user scrolls up again. how can I do that? Thank You.

Comment: on "onScroll" event set button visibility to visible and call method on scrollstop to run thread for 3 seconds post timer button will be set to invisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when use is scrolling up cancel the handlers pending events and start handler again

something like this

```
 myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

start handler in this way

```
myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable,LENGTH);
```